# HTML письмо в yandex.mail?

Tags: html, email, responsive

Есть готовый макет для email рассылки. Он корректно отображается в gmail/mail (+ пара клиентов), но при попытке реализовать рассылку через сервис yandex, последний удаляет viewport. Итог - некорректное отображение. Существуют ли пути обхода?